# JAVA Jersy2.0 Async Restful Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat

I have problem in deployment of JAVA Jersy2.0 Async Restful web service on tomcat server.

When I run this application locally on my PC with tomcat 7.0.41.0 It is working fine.
but when I deploy this service on my server with tomcat 7.0.42, It is giving error.
Please see below error.

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet helloworld.ApplicationConfig threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet helloworld.ApplicationConfig threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

root cause

org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader: The class com.sun.jersey.atom.abdera.impl.provider.entity.EntryProvider implementing provider interface javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader could not be instantiated: Cannot cast com.sun.jersey.atom.abdera.impl.provider.entity.EntryProvider to javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.fail(ServiceFinder.java:397)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.access$700(ServiceFinder.java:153)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder$LazyObjectIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:711)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinderBinder.configure(ServiceFinderBinder.java:68)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:169)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.install(AbstractBinder.java:313)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessagingBinders$MessageBodyProviders.configure(MessagingBinders.java:110)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:169)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.install(AbstractBinder.java:313)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerBinder.configure(ServerBinder.java:109)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:169)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.bind(Injections.java:157)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:147)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:137)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:265)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:262)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.jersey.atom.abdera.impl.provider.entity.EntryProvider to javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader
    java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3005)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder$LazyObjectIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:654)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinderBinder.configure(ServiceFinderBinder.java:68)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:169)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.install(AbstractBinder.java:313)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessagingBinders$MessageBodyProviders.configure(MessagingBinders.java:110)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:169)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.install(AbstractBinder.java:313)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerBinder.configure(ServerBinder.java:109)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:169)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.bind(Injections.java:157)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:147)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:137)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:265)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:262)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: hi Mahesh Patel did you solve it?

Comment: We have found that server installation is might be wrong, so we have re-install tomcat on server and issue is resolved at that time. but some time i am still getting this error randomly, and after restart tomcat is working fine. So as of now i am getting this error randomly.